# Global static variable not changing value

Tags: c#, webforms

I'm trying to make an application where the administrator can change some global values that it will affect the application for every user.

I tried to use static

Class

```
public static class Inventario
{
    public static int FiltroEtiquetas;

    public static int NumLocalizacoes;

    public static void GetInventario()
    {

    }
}
```

Page

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   txtFiltroEtiquetas.Text = Inventario.FiltroEtiquetas.ToString();
   txtNumLocalizacoes.Text = Inventario.NumLocalizacoes.ToString();
}
protected void btnSaveInventaryChanges_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

   Inventario.FiltroEtiquetas = Convert.ToInt32(txtFiltroEtiquetas.Text);
   Inventario.NumLocalizacoes = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumLocalizacoes.Text);
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "CallMyFunction", "ShowToast('OK', 'topCenter','success', 'Alterações Guardadas com sucesso.', '2000')", true);
 }
```

Whenever i open the modal the value is always 0, it won't save the changes

Comment: Just let me confirm, you want your administrator to be able to change some settings and then these settings will affect every other user using the system ?

Comment: Yes like some global values

Comment: OK then. why don't you create some AppSettings inside of your web.config files?, or better why not create a database table with these settings and a page for the administrator to view/edit these settings, and then you could load it with the start of your user's session

Comment: Didn't know you could add and change global values in web config. I will look into this approach and see if i can avoid making a new table in database

Comment: check this out for starting: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/815786/how-to-store-and-retrieve-custom-information-from-an-application-confi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On page load you are resetting the both the textboxes with your global variables and on button click you are doing reverse so its kind of reset. That's why you are seeing 0 value.

You need to remove the code from page_load or you need to apply some condition over that.

You can implement something like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(!IsPostBack)
   {
      txtFiltroEtiquetas.Text = Inventario.FiltroEtiquetas.ToString();
      txtNumLocalizacoes.Text = Inventario.NumLocalizacoes.ToString();
   }
}
```

Comment: yes but there is a problem or i don't know if this is the right approach. The values are lost if i close the application. I'm still a beginner and i'm not sure how will these values persist when application will be on server

Comment: @Jackal,  data does not get lost basically it get reset on page load, so remove the code from from Page_Load and it should work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think its really not a good idea to use the static variable in this scenario. I think you are better off using a application variable.

Comment: I'm looking into variables in web config file, i'm not sure which one is better for this situation